# tortoise svn commit failed on new repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise svn 1.9.x on windows 32 bit. all my other repositories work fine. i created a new one and have checked it out. when I try to create a folder and commit I get following error.

> The POST request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 3: not well-formed (invalid token) (/repos/aukocgcw/!svn/me)

I have checked permission and space they are fine.

Comment: Open the URL in a browser. I bet it displays an error message or an unrelated web site.

Comment: Additionally, that appears to be HTTP. TortoiseSVN does not even bundle an HTTP server.

Comment: I had to `chmod 777` on the repository on server. it is working now